# PHP is there any difference between 0.0 and 0.00?

Tags: php, c, floating-point, precision

Considering PHP8.1+, all syntaxes are valid:

```
var_dump(0.0); // outputs float(0)
var_dump(0.00); // also outputs float(0)
var_dump(0.0000000); // --||--
// ...
```

Is there any ***technical*** (even in the C background) difference between these definitions?

Does it somehow affect precision or not at all? - if not - why is such syntax allowed?

Does it have anything to do with the fact this goes ***both*** ways? : `var_dump(000042.42000000);` is also valid syntax ...

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ such a syntax be allowed? Whatever you write simply gets transformed into an internal floating point value (which has nothing to do with what you typed), and the superfluous decimal places simply get truncated in the process. Whatever way you write it, it all has the numerical value of zero, and that's the only thing that gets stored internally.

Comment: Because it could imply precision setting of float (which from what I know is fixed in PHP). So there is no technical differences and no consequences?

Comment: The number of decimal places used is only relevant to a mathematician or an engineer, and implies the accuracy of the data. For example `1.200` is more accurate than `1.2` but when parsed by a program they are identical.

Comment: @deceze: The question does not ask whether such a syntax is allowed; it explicitly states it is valid. It asks whether there is a difference between the definitions. In fact, there is, as PHP has no formal specification, PHP is typically implemented using C, and the C standard allows `strtod` to produce different values for different forms of floating-point literals that would nominally have the same value.

Comment: This question was wrongfully downvoted. It asks a valid question, to which the answer is in fact that different floating-point literals may yield different values even though they nominally represent the same value, because there is no specification that they must yield the same value.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Re “For example `1.200` is more accurate than `1.2` but when parsed by a program they are identical.”: The question asks whether there is a **technical** difference between the definitions. Can you show any **technical** requirement that they produce the same value? The C standard (which is relevant, see my answer) allows them to be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not have a formal specification. Therefore, there is no formal specification that says `0.0` and `0.00` resolve to the same value. While this is unlikely for `0.0` and `0.00`, there are other floating-point literals whose parsing may yield different values even though the literals nominally represent the same value, as explained below.

[The manual PHP does have](https://www.php.net/download-docs.php) appears to say little about the parsing of floating-point literals. (I did not examine the whole document, just the “Floating point numbers” subsection of the “Type System” section.)

PHP is typically implemented using C. The C standard allows floating-point literals of different source forms to result in different values even if they nominally designate the same number. This is by omission in C 2018 6.4.4.2 5, which says that literals of the same form yield the same number, “All floating constants of the same source form<sup>77)</sup> shall convert to the same internal format with the same value”, but omits specifying that “constants” of the different form but same nominal value convert to the same value. Footnote 77, which is non-normative, makes this explicit: “`1.23`, `1.230`, `123e-2`, `123e-02`, and `1.23L` are all different source forms and thus need not convert to the same internal format and value.”

PHP source code is of course not C source code. However, it would be natural for a PHP implementation in C to use the standard C library facilities to parse PHP source code. In particular, we might find `strtod` used to parse floating-point literals. Then we are faced with the fact that `strtod` is specified in reference to the rule in 6.4.4.2 cited above. C 2018 7.22.1.3 specifies `strtod`, and paragraph 5 says:

> …  the sequence of characters starting with the first digit or the decimal-point character (whichever occurs first) is interpreted as a floating constant according to the rules of 6.4.4.2,…

The allowance that different forms might produce different values is primarily to allow for the historic difficulties of parsing exponential notation. `4.2` and `42000000000000000000000000000000000000000e-40` are nominally the same value. However, parsing the latter is difficult because 10<sup>40</sup> is not representable in formats commonly used for hardware floating-point. It requires 81 bits in the significand, while the widest significand in common hardware is typically 53 or 64 bits. So literals like this cannot be parsed merely by computing the value of the significand and multiplying or dividing by the value of the exponent. Therefore, software that can parse floating-point values with *correct rounding* must be specially crafted. When C standard passages quoted above were written, it was not expected that parsing floating-point numbers would be done with the rigor necessary to produce correctly rounded results. Today, such software is known and available thanks to academic research. However, it is not necessarily present in all implementations of the standard C libraries.

I would expect `0.0` and `0.00` to yield the same value, exactly zero, because the parsing of the significand will produce zero, and the difficulties of computing the results of exponential notation or very long significands will not affect zero. Similarly, I would hope that even modest parsing software would yield the same values for `1.38` and `138e-2` because the calculations involved are well within the range where all the required values are representable in hardware floating-point formats, provided `138e-2` is calculated as 138 / 100 rather than 138 • .01. However, it would not be too surprising if this did not hold in amateur software.

However, for exponents of large magnitude, I would expect equality for different forms of the same number only if the software were deliberately written using published algorithms for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for understanding the core of the question - are you implying that if the parser is able to parse the number - regardless of leading or appended `0` s around a float will always be. basically, discarded?

Comment: @jave.web: No, neither the PHP manual nor the C standard requires that, and poor software might produce different values for `4.2` than for `4.2000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.